# Sencha Touch 2 - How to Abort store load with ajax/json

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch-2, store, abort

How can I abort a store load while the ajax call is still executing? I have a simple store with proxy type of 'ajax' and 'json' reader.

The documentation does not indicate any way to abort this. I have noticed that jsonp does allow aborting a load in progress. Do I have to switch to jsonp?

The motivation here is that I have a search bar and list object that gets populated with results. The actual search on the backend can take 5-10 seconds. So if a user starts a search then quickly wants to do another search (in case, for example, the first search was a typo), then the new search needs to abort the first search ajax call. Otherwise, I am seeing mixed results showing up in my search results.

As usual, any help is greatly appreciated!

Mohammad

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?232899

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have used in the past to solve this exact problem is to track each request with an incrementing counter and as requests complete I check the counter and if a request has been made with a higher counter I disregard the result.